# Reading binary data in Java

Tags: java, binary, binary-data

So for a project I am working on, I need to be reading binary data from .FRX files into my Java project. Java's standard byte reader however, keeps returning the wrong bytes for me, which I believe could be a result of Java's modified UTF8-encoding. If I use C#'s binary reading methods, I get the output that I require. An obvious (but proving to be difficult) solution is using C# and a DLL to wrap into the Java project, and I was just wondering if anyone has any simpler alternatives in Java, perhaps an alternative standard byte-reader which can be implemented in Java relatively easily.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

---

**Question update**

Here is my C# program, which returns the output I am looking for.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;

    public class GetFromFRX
    {
        public string getFromFRX(string filename, int pos)
        {
            StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder();
            using (BinaryReader b = new BinaryReader(File.Open("frmResidency.frx", FileMode.Open)))
            {
                try
                {
                    b.BaseStream.Seek(pos, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                    int length = b.ReadInt32();

                    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
                    {
                        buffer.Append(b.ReadChar());
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    return "Error obtaining resource\n" + e.Message;
                }

            }
            return buffer.ToString();
        }
    }
```

And here is some slightly differently formatted Java code:

```
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;

public class JavaReader {

   public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

      InputStream i = null;
      BufferedInputStream b = null;

      try{
         // open file
         i = new FileInputStream("frmResidency.frx");

         // input stream => buffed input stream 
         b = new BufferedInputStream(i);

         int numByte = b.available();
         byte[] buf = new byte[numByte];

         b.read(buf, 2, 3);

         for (byte d : buf) {
            System.out.println((char)d+":" + d);
         }
         }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
         }finally{
            if(i!=null)
               i.close();
            if(b!=null)
               b.close();
      } 
   }
}
```

Comment: Define "keeps returning the wrong bytes".

Comment: And show us your code. If you're just using `InputStream.read`, there *is* no encoding/decoding... (And no, there is definitely no need to use C# for this.)

Comment: Will update after re-writing Java, but essentially attempting to emulate output from this C# program.

Comment: Updated with equivalents I would think do the same thing.

Comment: doesn't java use a different byte-order than c# (which I assume to use the system byte order)?

Comment: `b.read(buf, 2, 3);` - why 2 and 3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Java code:

- You are using `available()` in a way which is specifically warned against in the Javadoc.
- You aren't checking the result returned by the `read()` method.
- You are reading into the buffer at offset 2 and then checking the entire buffer.
- You are reading bytes where your C# code reads characters.
- You aren't reading the length word.
- You aren't using methods like `DataInputStream.readInt()` which correspond to your C# code.